# Spring Data MongoDb TextCriteria matching characters or parts of words

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data

I do a TextQuery on my data that is text indexed

**My Class**

```
...
    @TextIndexed(weight = 1f)
    @Indexed
    var name: String? = null
    
    @TextIndexed(weight = 1f)
    @Indexed
    var lastName: String? = null
    
    @TextIndexed(weight = 1f)
    @Indexed
    var phone: String? = null
    
    @TextIndexed(weight = 1f)
    @Indexed
    var email: String? = null
...
```

**My Config**

```
val prospectTextIndex = TextIndexDefinitionBuilder()
            .named("text_myclass_search")
            .onField("name")
            .onField("lastname")
            .onField("phone")
            .onField("email")
            .build()
        mongoTemplate()?.indexOps(MyClass::class.java)?.ensureIndex(myclassTextIndex)
```

**My Repository**

```
    // Paginate over a full-text search result
    fun findAllBy(textCriteria: TextCriteria?, pageable: Pageable?): Page<Prospect?>?
```

**My Controller**

```
            val textCriteria: TextCriteria = TextCriteria
                .forDefaultLanguage()
                .matchingAny(searchQuery)
                .caseSensitive(false)
            val searchDirection: Sort = Sort.by(sortDirection, sortField)
            val pageRequest: Pageable = PageRequest.of(pageRequested - 1, DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE, searchDirection)
            myclassRepository.findAllBy(
                textCriteria,
                pageRequest
            )
```

I want to be able to search my TextIndex with characters in `searchQuery` like "J" or "goo" rather than full words or phrases, Is this possible ?